# Best way to keep ldap in sync with sql database

Tags: django, ldap

We are using an LDAP for user administration and authorization/authentication for a set of applications.

But there are also some applications were we need to have the LDAP user/group data accessible in an sql db2.

I'm using django to connect all these datasources and I was planning to use django celery to keep the LDAP and db2 in sync, where LDAP should be leading.

The following applies:
- The db2 user/groups tables cannot be written to, except from the scheduled celery task.
- The ldap model and db2 model both use "userid" as the primary key.
- The db2 table will insert if a userid cannot be found, and update only the changed fields, which are different on ldap then are on db2.

I was thinking of hashing the fields on LDAP and DB2 into a saved field, to check if the objects are in sync?

But what are the best practices to keep data integrity in this example?

Comment: Depends on which implementation of LDAP. AD? or ???. If you are within an enterprise, you should at least consider a commercial IDM product. Keeping things "in-sync" is not trivial.

Comment: We are using an OpenLdap implementation. That suffices for us. The application we are developing uses the synced ldap tables to determine if a user should receive an alert and where to send mails to. So it's kind of trivial data is in sync over ldap and database.